# What type of timer event should I use for a background process when my timer fires very quickly

Tags: c, multithreading, timer

I'm using a timer that can fire up to 5000 times a second.  At the same time, the process that is running the timer will have spawned 32 threads of its own.  Every time the timer fires, I want my threads to do something.

I can do this using any of the sigevent types (pulse, signal, or create a thread that sets a variable the other threads watch for), but I'm not sure which one would be most efficient.

I know threads are probably a bad idea as they are expensive and making so many every second will probably cause performance issues, so any ideas?

I would like it to perform the action ASAP once the timer has fired.  So what's the best type of event to use?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, this is coded in C

Comment: What language or framework are you using

Comment: You cannot realistically think about creating 32 threads every 200us - it's just... just don't do it.  Signaling 32 threads with events/semaphores to make them loop is, at least, more reasonable.  Can you give any more details about your overall design and what it does?  I would be wary of even signaling threads at that frequency, never mind trying to create them.

Comment: Well yes, I was going to create 32 at the beginning, and loop through them.  I will not be creating/terminating the 32 after that.  I was just need some way to signal them when the clock expires.

Comment: OK, well, do you need the threads to run exactly as many time as the clock times out, ie. even if some threads occasionally overrun the clock timeout?  If so, a semaphore for each thread would do.  If it does not matter if a timeout is occasionally missed, then an AutoResetEvent for each would be OK.  I'm still worried by the 200ns interval, however.  That is a very short time for a desktop OS.

Comment: Yea that's basically my worry too.  Each of the 32 threads calls a blocking write function.  What I wanted to do was, every time the timer fires, tell one of the threads to write.  I was going to keep a mutex lock in front of the write call to block it, and have the timer unlock the mutex.  So every time the timer fires, it writes once, and I can have many writes going on simultaneously.  I don't want any skipped writes, in case the timer resets more than once before a thread can write.  I guess using SIGEV_PULSE to control it would be ok?

Comment: If you must never miss a signal, even if the target thread is occasionally busy and cannot receive it, you need a synchronization primitive with a count, usually therefore, a semaphore.